# Perfino threshold for specific POJO methods

Tags: perfino

My business case: I want to receive an alert if too many login attempts occurs. Or too many failed tasks in the task queue of my application.

So I have multiple defined business transactions to track app performance and for the case above I have one more business transaction based on Pojo invocation method. It looks like it is not possible to assign threshold on this specific business transaction "Login attempt". The only one suitable value here is "Completed Transactions" but in this case an alert will be generated for all transactions I have, not only for "Login attempts"

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a "policy trigger" instead of a "threshold violation trigger".